# Devo usar rebase?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Estou trabalhando em uma reformulação da nossa aplicação web, em uma branch separada, digamos `new_interface`. Enquanto isso, outros desenvolvedores continuam na branch `master`, principalmente resolvendo bugs. Enquanto alguns arquivos podem divergir consideravelmente, preciso recuperar as correções que foram pelos outros desenvolvedores.

Até então tenho dado `merge` da `master` na minha branch (usando o TortoiseGit), porém da última vez isso não deu certo. Vários arquivos ficaram errados, mesmo alguns que não acusaram conflito. Parece que o `merge` escolheu a versão da `master`ao invés da versão reformulada.

Como alternativa para resolver essa situação, estou tentando estudando o `rebase`, porém ainda não sei se isso iria resolver o meu problema.

O `rebase` irá resolver a minha situação ou o resultado será o mesmo que o `merge`?

---

**Edit:**
Confirmei que apesar do sistema de edição de conflito ser um pouco diferente, o resultado final é bem parecido, inclusive com os mesmos problemas. 
Por exemplo, em alguns arquivos as mudanças pertencentes a `new_interface` sumiram no log final, em ambos métodos.

Terei que passar manualmente todas as modificações de uma branch para outra ou ainda há outra alternativa?

---

**Edit 2:**
Acabei fazendo merge mesmo (squash, recursive - patience), porém tive que ir arquivo por arquivo (inclusive os que não acusaram conflito) escolhendo quais mudanças eu queria incorporar e quais descartar.

Um erro que eu havia cometido da primeira vez que tentei o merge foi clicar em "resolve conflicts using mine" nos arquivos que queria manter integralmente intocados. Na verdade o certo seria marcar "revert", descartando a versão da `master` e mantendo o arquivo como antes do merge.

Comment: Quem tiver permissão para criar tags, poderia por favor colocar a tag `tortoisegit`?

Comment: Deves sempre usar `rebase` pois assim coloca os teus commits no fim da linha de alterações. Contudo, se as mudanças forem nas mesma linhas, isso pode dar erro que precisa ser resolvido manualmente. O ideal é sempre fazer commits com frequência mesmo que com pouco código e atualizar com todos os que estão a trabalhar no código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O resultado vai ser o mesmo. Tanto no rebase como no merge, se uma mesma linha é alterada nos dois ramos ele gera um conflito pra você resolver manualmente. Se alguma modificação do `master` passou sem dizer nada é porque o algoritmo do git não considerou ela um conflito.

Pra escolher entre rebase e merge é mais uma questão de gosto. A principal razão de ser do rebase é editar o histórico de commits para ser linear. Dependendo do seu workflow e de que modificação você esteja fazendo no histórico isso pode ser o que você quer ou não.

Voltando ao seu problema específico, em geral é uma boa idéia manter os branches "curtos" e não ficar fazendo vários merges do ramo master para o seu ramo de desenvolvimento. Se você não puder dar o merge do seu ramo devolta pro main rapidamente, talvez valha a pena tentar dar um rebase do seu branch pro topo do master, pra fingir que você começou a trabalhar nele hoje (do ponto do visto do histórico de commits)

Comment: De fato, testei aqui (em cópias de ambos ramos) e apesar dos conflitos serem resolvidos um por um ao invés de todos ao final, o resultado foi praticamente o mesmo. Ou seja, o problema continua.

Answer (score 0):

Nao. Se fizeres rebase `master` -> `new_interface`, os commits no `master` vao ser re-criados no teu branch. Ou seja, vao existir commits com o mesmo nome, conteudo, e diferentes hashes.